# Can radiative transfer theory be used to calculate an effective index of refraction?

Tags: refraction, phase-velocity, radiative-transfer

As I understand it, the (real) index of refraction is given by the ratio of speed of a monochromatic light wave in vacuo versus speed in medium. When it comes to the question of propagation of a light pulse in a (dispersive) medium I know that I need to calculate the group refractive index to obtain the propagation speed of the pulse.

My question specifically now is, if it is possible to use radiative transfer theory to calculate light pulse propagation in a scattering environment embedded within a medium (not vacuum)?

If the former is possible, can that speed be said to be the effective group velocity of the mixture of the scatterers and medium? Further can this effective group velocity be used to calculate an effective group refraction index?

Background: Although I have no working experience with radiative transfer theory I can imagine that it would be possible to use it for calculation of attenuation related values such as the imaginary part of the index of refraction, but I cannot see how it would be possible to get at the real part of the index of refraction.